# How can I extract parts of a Django Postgres DateRangeField

Tags: django, postgresql

I would appreciate some help. I can't get my head around this.
I want to use the **Django Postgres DateRangeField** for a model in my app.
It will hold two dates: a from-date and a to-date like in a booking system.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import DateRangeField

class Booking(models.Model)
    from_to = DateRangeField()
```

All works fine and nicely. I can play around with it in the Admin.
In order to confirm the booking, I'd like to extract the 2 dates in variables again, and that's where I hit a wall :)

The printed object looks a lot like a tuple to me, with from-date and to-date and the bounds-definition

```
DateRange(datetime.date(2017, 2, 1), datetime.date(2017, 3, 31), '[)')
```

however, any attempt to extract one of the dates fails.

```
fromdate = self.from_to(0)
'DateRange' object is not callable
```

I'm sure it's simple, however, there is no documentation about that (at least not any I could find)
Your help is more than appreciated.

Comment: You can see the method of `from_to`. Print `dir(self.from_to)`

Comment: Thank you! I keep always forgetting about this neat feature!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.Range

> Object attributes:
>
> lower
>      The lower bound of the range. None if empty or unbound.
>
> upper
>   The upper bound of the range. None if empty or unbound.

Comment: :) I swear I tried lower and upper.... however, I guess I called them like ...lower() ...  
yes, self.from_to.lower works flawless. 
I would give the answer an upvote, however, I still have not enough credits in stackoverflow to do so :( Thank you for the answer!

Comment: You are welcome. ;) Glad to help you. dir() is veryusefull. Never forget this function :p